# How to host jupyter notebooks on webserver and integrate with own webapp

Tags: javascript, python, html, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I am wondering if it is possible to integrate juypter notebooks with ones own web app? The target use case would be as follows:

I have a web application where there is some information and a button where the user can click to open a predefined jupyter notebook. I know how to build the webapp, but am wondering how to host jupyter in a way that it opens in separate tab once the user clicks the button, and that the code in the notebook gets excuted on my server?

Similar example would be how the MOOC site Coursera does it: Users of the site can open jupyter notebooks that Coursera is hosting.